# Most efficient way to search file for byte patterns in Elixir

Tags: elixir, id3

I am searching for id3 tags in a song file. A file can have id3v1, id3v1 extended tags (located at the end of the file) as well as id3v2 tags (usually located at the beginning). For the id3v1 tags, I can use File.read(song_file) and pull out the last 355 bytes (128 + 227 for the extended tag). However, for the id3v2 tags, I need to search through the file from the beginning looking for a 10 byte id3v2 pattern. I want to avoid any overhead from opening and closing the same file repeatedly as I search for the different tags, so I thought the best way would be to use File.stream!(song_file) and send the file stream to different functions to search for the different tags.

```
def parse(file_name) do
  file_stream = File.stream!(file_name, [], 1)
  id3v1_tags(file_stream)
  |> add_tags(id3v2_tags(file_stream))
end

def id3v1_tags(file_stream) do
  tags = Tags%{} #struct containing desired tags
  << id3_extended_tag :: binary-size(227), id3_tag :: binary-size(128) >> = Stream.take(file_stream, -355)
  id3_tag = to_string(id3_tag)
  if String.slice(id3_tag,0, 3) == "TAG" do
    Map.put(tags, :title, String.slice(id3_tag, 3, 30))
    Map.put(tags, :track_artist, String.slice(id3_tag, 33, 30))
    ...
  end
  if String.slice(id3_extended_tag, 0, 4) == "TAG+" do
    Map.put(tags, :title, tags.title <> String.slice(id3_extended_tag, 4, 60))
    Map.put(tags, :track_artist, tags.track_artist <> String.slice(id3_extended_tag, 64, 60))
    ...
  end
end

def id3v2_tags(file_stream) do
  search for pattern:
  <<0x49, 0x44, 0x33, version1, version2, flags, size1, size2, size3, size4>>
end
```

1) Am I saving any runtime by creating the File.stream! once and sending it to the different functions (I will be scanning tens of thousands of files, so saving a bit of time is important)? Or should I just use File.read for the id3v1 tags and File.stream! for the id3v2 tags?

2) I get an error in the line:

```
  << id3_extended_tag :: binary-size(227), id3_tag :: binary-size(128) >> = Stream.take(file_stream, -355)
```

because Stream.take(file_stream, -355) is a function, not a binary. How do I turn it into a binary that I can pattern match?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you but if I were you, I'd really avoid magic numbers. I'm assuming the -355 is the sum of 128 and 227?  If I were you I'd set a module attribute called `@id_extended_tag_binsize` to 227 and `@id3_tag_binsize` to 128 and then use those attributes in the Stream.take like this: Stream.take(file_stream, -(`@id_extended_tag_binsize` + `@id3_tag_binsize`)) Less error prone and far easier to read and understand.

Comment: First off, File.stream needs to be told to read bytes rather than lines using the syntax File.stream!(path, [:read  ], :bytes ) .  Next I don't think the -355 can be used with Stream.take since stream is not a list but a potential list that needs to be finalised with a Stream.to_list call.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have changed my code accordingly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe your implementation is being unnecessarily complex due to the reliance on stream. Make it work, make it pretty then make it fast (but only if necessary).

For simplicity, I would first load everything into memory. Just use `File.read!/1`. Then you can use the functions in :binary module to search for patterns (`:binary.match/2`), split it (`:binary.split/2`) or grab a certain part (`:binary.part/3`). There is no need to mix File.stream and File.read too, just read it once and pass that same binary around.

Also, very important, **don't use the String module**. String is meant to work UTF-8 encoded binaries. You want to use the :binary module for all byte level operation.

Finally, `Stream.take/2` always returns functions as it is lazy. You want to use `Enum.take/2` instead (it accepts streams as streams are also enumerables). Although, as I said, I would skip the stream stuff altogether.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. I will take your advice and use File.read!/1. I didn't know that about the String module. I thought that if the bytes were characters, then you could treat them as either binaries or strings.